# Currency Symbol on wrong side in PHP output

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am having a problem with the currency symbol being on the wrong side of the figures within a single line of code;

I am quite new to this and have tried different methods but gave in for some help.

If I am honest I haven't searched Google as I am not sure what I am searching for.

Here is the link of code:

```
<td><?=$tra['cash'].' '.get_currency_symbol($site['currency_code'])?></td>
```

the output of the above code is `2.00 £`

I am needing it to display as `£2.00`

I know it has something to do with the `"get_currency_symbol"` but when I try to move this I get errors.

Getting the answer to this issue would be great, but please post links to some information regarding this.

I have tried to read manuals to learn this stuff but a hands on approach suits me better.

Comment: Consider learning this
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
And this
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td><?php echo get_currency_symbol($site['currency_code']) . $tra['cash']; ?></td>
```